# Patron de Diseño Django

Tags: django, patrones-de-diseño

acudo a uds mas como una consulta que como un problema , la cuestion es que deseo saber si existe quiza algun patron de diseño especifico para django algo como esto:

```
Las aplicaciones deben estar dentro de una carpeta llamada apps.
Los html deben estar dentro de templates
---
---
---
etc....
```

La guia que he leido y aplicado es de PEP 8 donde manifiesta sobre indentacion , clases, funciones entre otros mas no sobre el diseño en si de django.

Gracias de Antemano..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django genera una estructura de directorios base, sobre ella podemos editar o modificar archivos y carpetas para tener un mejor orden en nuestro proyecto.

Dentro de la raíz del proyecto podemos crear nuevas "aplicaciones" y cuando son muchas lo que se acostumbra a hacer es agruparlas todas en una carpeta "apps" o "modulos".

```
cd apps
django-admin startapp app1
```

De igual forma se hace con los archivos HTML se dejan en una carpeta "templates" o "plantillas" y se agrupan todos los archivos.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Notese que el parámetro DIRS apunta al directorio "templates" donde estan los .html

También es buena practica es dejar varios archivos settings.py con diferentes nombres como "development.py", "production.py", "testing.py" y "base.py".

Otra cosa es que se suele dejar todos los modulos requerimientos del proyectos en un archivo de requerimientos "requerimientos.txt" o "requirements.txt"

```
pip install freeze
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

La estructura del proyecto quedaría algo así:

```
-django-project
    -apps
        -app1
        -app2
        -app3
        -app4
    -djangoproject
        -settings
             -base.py
             -development.py
             -production.py
             -testing.py
        -wsgi.py
        -urls.py
        -views.py
    -templates
        -html1
        -html2
        -html3
        -html4
    -manage.py
    -requirements.txt
```

Adicional a todo esto, tambien se acostumbra a dejar los archivos estaticos "statics" y el almacenamiento "storage" en otro servicio aparte dedicado solo a almacenamiento. Lo mismo pasa con las bases de datos, también se suelen dejar en otro servidor y en el backend se configura la conexión remota. (Todo esto se debe hacer en un archivo .env oculto que tenga todas las variables de configuración como KEYS o PASSWORD o HOSTS

```
DATABASES = {
     'default': {
          'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
          'NAME': os.getenv('DATABASE_NAME'),
          'USER': os.getenv('DATABASE_USER'),
          'PASSWORD': os.getenv('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
          'HOST': os.getenv('DATABASE_HOST'),
          'PORT': os.getenv('DATABASE_PORT')
      }
}
```

y pues muchas mas cosas que hacen falta seguir describiendo jeje. salu2.

Comment: Sin duda una gran explicacion.. muchas gracias... quiza algun link o libro de sugerencia para aprender mas sobre django..gracias

Comment: la documentacion oficial del framework sin duda :)